# Updating a record in the database

Tags: sql, oracle, function, plsql, commit

I have an EJB based project created in JDeveloper and I have an auto filled form with data. The user can change any data he wants and finally he should click "commit"/"rollback" button and the data in the database should be changed. The requirement for me is to create a function in a package that RUTURNS fault/ok if the change is successful. I have created a procedure but a function is more appropriate for this action. Here is my procedure.

```
  PROCEDURE edit(
      p_i_id   NUMBER,
      p_i_name    VARCHAR2);



  PROCEDURE EDIT(
      p_i_id   NUMBER,
      p_i_name    VARCHAR2)
  IS
  BEGIN
    UPDATE Table_name
    SET NAME    = p_i_name
    WHERE COLUMN_ID = p_i_id;
  END EDIT;
```

Any ideas about the function? Thank you!

Comment: You can get the result from a stored procedure.
Just use an OUT parameter.

Functions are for results.

Answer (score 2):

Hope this helps.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION edit(
    p_i_id   NUMBER,
    p_i_name VARCHAR2)
  RETURN VARCHAR2
AS
BEGIN
  UPDATE EMP SET ENAME = p_i_name WHERE EMPNO = p_i_id;
  IF SQL%ROWCOUNT <> 0 THEN
    RETURN 'OK';
  ELSE
    RETURN 'FAULT';
  END IF;
END;
```